# No spacing between code spans in list items

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, code-formatting

While editing profile, this is how the preview shows list items containing code spans:

> [image: preview]

But this is the actual result after editing profile:

> [image: actual rendering]

Expected result: There should be spacing between the code spans in list items as shown in preview.

Comment: Formatting technology names as code? Not sure about that…

Comment: @Xufox Yea I should've used tags for that... But someone might actually want to use code snippets...

Comment: Oh wait... If I use `[tag:name]` then I can't redirect it to a particular URL like  `[tag:name](http://whereiwantogo)` top users for example... so I think code is my best bet.

Comment: You don't have to use the `[tag:...]` syntax, but you still shouldn't abuse code formatting for things that aren't code. I see no particular reason why the names of tags should be set apart with a monospaced font.

Answer (score 13):

The margin between list items is added in http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/all.css

```css
.post-text ul li, .wmd-preview ul li,
.post-text ol li, .wmd-preview ol li {
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
```

So it affects posts and previews. The bio preview is also a preview, but the bio is not a post.

Either make the bio a post, or set the margin to the bio too

```css
.post-text ul li, .wmd-preview ul li, .bio ul li,
.post-text ol li, .wmd-preview ol li, .bio ol li {
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You might want to use the Html line break tag `<br>` or may be add some margin-bottom?